# How to restrict the users not to go above a specified home directory in QFileDialog in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In QFileDialog in PyQt5 I wish to restrict the user access to a specified home directory and its subdirectories.
I have found a solution for c++ [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76690/qfiledialog-restrict-for-the-users-only-the-respective-path), but I could not successfully implement it in PyQt5 :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QMessageBox

class restrictedFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, homedir):
        super().__init__()
        self.directoryEntered.connect(self.ontDirectoryChanged)
        self.homedir = homedir
        self.filtertxt = "Data files (*.dat);;All Files (*)"
        self.options = QFileDialog.Options()
        self.options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        self.filePath, _ = self.getOpenFileName(None, "Load data file", self.homedir, 
                                                  self.filtertxt, options=self.options)

    def ontDirectoryChanged(self, dirName):
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Restricted directory', 'Directory haschanged.')
        if dirName.startswith(self.homedir):
            pass
        else:
            self.setDirectory(self.homedir)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Restricted directory', 'Cannot walk up in the path.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    homedir = 'C:\\Users'
    rd = restrictedFileDialog(homedir)
    if rd.filePath:
        print(rd.filePath)
    app.exec_()
```

The problem is that the slot 'ontDirectoryChanged' is never triggered.
I know that the signal 'directoryEntered' gives a python string containing the current directory name, and I am not sure whether my slot 'ontDirectoryChanged' is bound correctly.

Comment: `getOpenFileName` is a static function, if you use it your class is completely useless: dialog static functions **always** return a privately constructed dialog, that is only using the option set in the function arguments; trying to set properties or connect to signals of a previously created instance is completely useless in this case, as that instance will *never* be used. You must properly setup the class open mode and call its `exec()` or `open()`, then your connected function will be called.

Comment: The QFileDialog static functions create predefined QFileDialog instances with specific properties set, but you can do the same by properly subclassing QFileDialog and setting the required options (in your case, setting the `fileMode` to `ExistingFile`), as explained in [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#details). After that, create the instance as you already did, but then call it's `exec()`, and get its [`selectedFiles()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#selectedFiles) after that.

Comment: I reverted your last edit since I don't think the added paragraph contained any new information, and Questions are not meant for discussions. However, I do agree that this question seems to be specifically about Python so the C++ question/answer is not a valid target. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @musicamante, do you care to post this as an answer, or to edit the current answer to include this information? Comments might get lost in the future, and that would make the current (only) answer much less valuable (it will then become a code-only answer). Tamas can also do this of course, or even I could, but it would only be fair to give you proper credits for the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @musicamante's hints I could solve the problem. Here is a minimal solution:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QMessageBox

class restrictedFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, homedir):
        super().__init__()
        self.homeDir = os.path.normpath(homedir)
        self.setDirectory(self.homeDir)
        self.directoryEntered.connect(self.onDirectoryChanged)

    def onDirectoryChanged(self, dirName):
        dn = os.path.normpath(dirName)
        if not dn.startswith(self.homeDir):
            self.setDirectory(self.homeDir)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Restricted path', 'Cannot walk above the home directory:\n%s' % self.homeDir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    rfd = restrictedFileDialog('C:\\Users')
    rfd.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
    rfd.setWindowTitle('Load data file')
    rfd.setNameFilter("Data files (*.dat);;All Files (*)")
    rfd.selectNameFilter("Data files (*.dat)")
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    rfd.setOptions(options)
    if rfd.exec():
        print(rfd.selectedFiles())
    else:
        print('Dialog is cancelled.')
```